# Reducing chemistry to physics

Tags: philosophy-of-science

What is the status of reducing chemistry to physics? I mean, to be able to derive the laws of chemistry from quantum physics.

From what I'm seeing online, it seems like this is considered possible in theory, but not in practice due to lack of computing power.

This feels like a huge gap in humanity's knowledge... I mean, I can understand not being able to reduce biology to chemistry, because we're dealing with billions of years of evolution. But reducing chemistry to physics is a purely mathematical problem isn't it?

Is there any ongoing project with the goal of reducing chemistry to physics?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about philosophy. It might fit under the history of science SE?

Comment: I disagree; there's no way this is not a philosophy question. This is a central topic in philosophy of science, and discussed in many articles in the SEP. And I took nearly an entire course on it in a Philosophy department. What you might be missing is that the best example of that reduction was accomplished by a philosopher—Ernest Nagel, in *The Structure of Science*—not scientists. Historians of science would balk at the question.

Comment: @ChristopherE There was a long discussion of the fit issue for these kinds of questions on meta http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/questions-about-philosophy-of-physics and there is no consensus. As best as I can tell the issue with this question is that while the topic itself has a philosophical dimension the OP does not show sufficient awareness of it to focus the answers on philosophy, too much of elementary non-philosophical explaining will have to be done first. You may be able to fix it, but only by doing radical edit.

Comment: Well, I understand the concern about taking on science questions, but I respectfully disagree again, that this is that kind of question. The question in the thread you link to asks for a science result. Here, the answer is about what philosophers have done, not what scientists have done. Nagel, a philosopher, reduced thermodynamics to statistical mechanics, at least with respect to his understanding of "reduction," and that was an important achievement in philosophy. One can answer this question referring only to philosophy journals.

Comment: Many many years ago (more than 40!) when I was in undergraduate university, my university had a requirement that all physics majors had to take 2 semesters of beginning chemistry. It was meant to be taken during your 1st year. What most people did, however, was take it in their senior year. It was extremely easy after 3 years of physics courses...no need to study.

Comment: @ChristopherE I didn't seem your earlier comment. *What is the question about philosophy here?* I don't see it nor do I see what you're reading into the question about him asking specifically about what philosophers have done and seeking an answer "referring only to philosophy journals". If you can get the OP to focus his question, great. If not, you can ask a better focused question that's on-topic about philosophy and reduction of chemistry to physics.

Comment: I think I see the philosophical issue, but the question still should be improved. "From what I'm seeing online" - there are _lots_ of things online, to what exactly does the OP refer? "lack of computing power" - is this a few more processor generations kind of issue, or a more-computing-power-than-ever-will-be-possible kind of issue? There are lots of systems that cannot be easily reduced to their components, is there a particular reason why chemistry would be? Even if this were possible, it's not clear what problems are made easier by this reduction.

Comment: @virmaior the reduction of chemistry to physics is a typical question of philosophy of science, and a widely discussed one, by no mean is it off-topic. If the question should be closed it is for other reasons. I vote to reopen.

Comment: Here is some resources on the topic: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chemistry/#CheRed

Comment: @quen_tin I understand the idea is behind the reduction of chemistry to physics and philosophical questions about it. I don't grasp that the OP is asking about *philosophy*. They seem to be asking "what's the status of the reduction." I repeat what I asked ChristopherE but never received an answer to: *can you reword what you take to be the question about or within philosophy to be that the OP is asking?* It's rather unclear to me what question about philosophy they mean to ask or if they mean to ask one (alternately, ask a better question and a comment pointing to it here).

Comment: Or to reword why I think this is off-topic, the OP seems to be asking how progress is going on reducing chemistry to physics (i.e. an update on the status of the project). The OP doesn't seem to be asking any question about what such an undertaking means or how chemistry and physics do relate...  Do you or one of the other people voting to re-open see a specific question *about* philosophy here rather than a chance to rant about the general relation the OP might not be asking about?

Comment: @virmaior I see the question "does chemistry reduce to physics" as a philosophical one because the concept of theoretical reduction is not really part of any scientific field (at most there is overlap: if scientists pretend to account for chemistry with physical concepts, the question is: what exactly do they mean by that?) The OP is asking quite explicitly if theoretical reduction is a purely mathematical matter and if a lack of reduction is a huge gap in our understanding of nature. Maybe it's too much for one question but these are clearly philosophical topics.

Comment: @virmaior also the fact that it should be possible in principle but that we lack computational resources, if confirmed, would raise interesting questions (is it still a huge gap in our understanding?)

Comment: (1) Is the OP asking, *does chemistry reduce to physics*? (2) If that's the question, how isn't the question of whether such a reduction is possible not merely opinion based? (3) When you claim that OP is asking whether the reduction is purely mathematical, I read the OP as **declaring** its purely mathematical. (4) regarding your second comment, "raising interesting questions" is nowhere near identical to raising ones that are a good fit for an SE.